# Passing variables between classes, in Java!

Tags: java

I am a beginner learning Java.
I have two classes,

```
public class myClassA {
    //It contains the main function

    yourClass tc = new yourClass();

    .... many codes...

    public void printVariable()
    {
        // print here
    }

}


class yourClass {

    void I_AM_a_button_press()  // function
    {
        // I want to call printVariable() in myClassA here, But how?
    }
}
```

How can I call a method defined in one class from another?

Comment: Use/Learn **Method arguments**. Through arguments you can pass values to the method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass in an instance of `myClassA` into a constructor for `yourClass`, and store a reference to it.

```
class yourClass {

    private myClassA classAInstance;

    public yourClass(myClassA a)
    {
        classAInstance = a;
    }

    void I_AM_a_button_press()  // function
    {
        classAInstance.printVariable();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to make a new instance of myClassA and call that method from that new object

```
void I_AM_a_button_press()  // function
    {
        myClassA a = new myClassA();
        a.printVariable();
    }
```

Or you can pass an instance of myClassA in through a constructor

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
public void I_AM_a_button_press(){
  myClassA a = new  myClassA();
  a.printVariable();
}
```